# How did Barbra Streisand learn of the California Coastal Records image of her house, when it had only been downloaded 4 times before her counsel did?

Tags: popular-culture, internet

The [Streisand Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect) got named because of Barbra Streisand learning about her house being in the California Coastal Records database and kicking up a huge fuss about it.

But how did she discover that her house was there, when it had only been downloaded 4 times before her counsel did it, as said in the [Tentative Ruling](http://www.californiacoastline.org/streisand/slapp-ruling-tentative.pdf) of the lawsuit that was related to the Effect?

> Tentative ruling, page 6, stating, "Image 3850 was download six times, twice to the Internet address of counsel for plaintiff". In addition, two prints of the picture were ordered—one by Streisand's counsel and one by Streisand's neighbor.

Comment: It appears that downloading and viewing are two separate functions according to the court papers you cite: '*Once access to the image is obtained*, it is possible to enlarge the image, ***to download it to the user's computer*** and to print the enlarged image.' So any number of people might have viewed the image, only 4 pressed the download button.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a history question

Comment: @justCal Presumably system logs would have told how many had viewed the smaller image, though I suspect the lawyers may not have been smart enough to understand that.

Comment: Technically, it's not possible to view the image without downloading it in some format.

Comment: Given the lengths Streisand alleges she went through to make her property private, she might have employed a service to keep an eye out for photographs of her or her property. [See 3, 4 and 5 of her complaint](https://www.californiacoastline.org/streisand/complaint.pdf). She also might have been tipped off by their helicopter (see 6 and https://www.californiacoastline.org/project.html).